# port wp7 phonegap application to win8(not wp8)

Tags: windows, cordova

I've developed a hybrid phonegap application for wp7/iOS/Android. Now customer wants to support window 8(not the windows phone 8). Actually it is possible to create javascript windows store app, but I can't find any way to use C# plugins. Is it possible to create win 8 app without rewriting whole project?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about the plugin support for Win8 but there is a cordova project for Win8 that might be helpful, I'm guessing you would probably have to add to your plugins to support it, depending on what plugins your using.

https://github.com/apache/cordova-windows